# How to open multiple popup window's in ASP.NET on button click

Tags: asp.net

I have struck in one doubt.

I am using one asp button.  In this button click event I'm using `if` and `else` condition.

`If` block shows one popup and `else` block show another popup:

```
if (Session["id"] != null)
{
      //one popup 
}
else
{
    //Second pop up Show
}

<asp:Button ID="btnAvailabilty" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Check Availability" OnClick="btnAvailabilty_Click" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to write that in client side if you need to write a JavaScript code there,

```
if (Session["id"] != null) {
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "something", 
       "alert('Your message');",
    true);
} else {
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "something", 
       "alert('Your other message');",
    true);
}
```

You can also try to run the message variable to be changed, while leaving maximum of the code in one statement,

```
var message = "Your message";
if (Session["id"] == null) {
    message = "Your other message";
}

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "something", 
           $"alert({message});", // Requires C# 6
        true);
```

If you can write native JavaScript, such as Razor, then that will go like,

```
<script>
    @if (Session["id"] != null) {
        alert('Your message');
    } else {
        alert('Your other message');
    }
</script>
```

Depends on your need.

Comment: Hii Afzaal thanks for your solution. here i need javascript popup like

Comment: div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:444px;">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
      <form style="margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;">

Comment: You can write any _arbitrary_ code there, it is entirely your choice. I just gave an example of `alert`. You can chose from a number of options.